# What is correct path

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

What is correct path to my hhconfig.xml from web xml?

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:/hhconfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>hhconfig</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>hhconfig</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my screen from project tree

http://zapodaj.net/22e3adc3a776f.png.html

Comment: you can add your `hhconfig.xml` file into `src/main/resources` package and change param-value `classpath:hhconfig.xml` instead of `classpath:/hhconfig.xml`.

Comment: Then i have :ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hhconfig-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hhconfig-servlet.xml]

Comment: you can change your xml file name `hhconfig.xml` to `hhconfig-servlet.xml`. I'm not sure but i think it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hhconfig.xml` must be located directly in `src/main/resources` - currently it is under `src/main/resources/META-INF`. All files from `src/main/resources` will be added to `<war>/WEB-INF/classes`, thus they will be available on your web app's classpath.

You also need to change `classpath:/hhconfig.xml` to `classpath:hhconfig.xml`. Check [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) for examples of resource strings.